# Draw line using pdfHTML add-on iText 7

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I'm using pdfHTML to generate Pdf. I want to draw line in the document.
For that I used below code.

```
<head>
    <style>
        hr {
            border-colour: black;
            border: none;
            height: 0.25pt;
            color: #333;
            background-color: #333;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <hr/>
    <p>Paragraph2</p>
    <hr/>
</body>
```

Draw lines. But some lines are thickness than the other. I have used same styles. How to fix this issue?

Comment: could u plz add your code to view what exactly problem is?

Comment: Please attach your code and the result that you get currently